# Textmate-like keys scheme for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate, shortcut

I use Eclipse on windows at my new job but I'm much a Textmate user. Does anyone has a textmate-like keys scheme for Eclipse ?

Comment: I know that you can set your own key bindings in eclipse and you can switch to emacs style by default. I'm also searching for a TextMate schema to use in Eclipse. Let you know when I found some

Comment: I know that you can define your own key scheme and then save it, but I was hopping it already existed. I Guest I'll have to make one myself.

Comment: If you do so, would be great if you would open source it. I didn't take the time yet to do it. But happy to contribute if there is a project for it.